Flutter Release apk not working properly, Debug apk also not working in my device but emulator working well
I am trying to build an app and the app is running fine on the emulator ( Sign in and Sign Up are working fine with the API)
I have try to add internet permission also but not working kindly help and guide
Verbose screenshot for your response

I want to run and check release apk in my device
